# Neo4j Error - Failed to find an expected property (cypher) in the JSON at path data

Tags: neo4j, neo4jclient

I'm trying to connect to a remote Neo4j database using Neo4jClient (C#).

I get the following error when calling the "Connect" method on my Neo4jClient object instance:

**System.InvalidOperationException: While trying to map some JSON into an object of type Neo4jClient.ApiModels.RootApiResponse, we failed to find an expected property (cypher) in the JSON at path data.**

And this is how i'm creating the object and calling the method:

```
var dbClient = new GraphClient(myServerIpAddress, new HttpClientWrapper());
dbClient.Connect();
```

I can access the DB just fine using the browser. Any idea on what could be causing this issue?

- Neo4jClient - version 1.0.0.657
- Newtonsoft.Json - version 6.0.3.17227
- Neo4j Database - version 2.1.3

Answer (score 4, accepted):

According to the [documentation](https://github.com/Readify/Neo4jClient/wiki/connecting), GraphClient's first parameter is always a Uri. I'm not sure what you're passing in `myServerIpAddress`, but it should be a Uri of the form `http://hostname:port/db/data`. I suggest your error is occurring because you're not supplying either the correct port (default for Neo4j is 7474) or the /db/data path?

Comment: Thanks...That was the exact problem. I didn't have "/db/data" as part of the URI.